# Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'int *')

Tags: c++

I'm creating a simple array program where I am supposed to copy the values from my first array and print them out through another array. I keep getting a Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'int *') error and its confusing as I have not change the way I have been doing things and I've been going through my previous lines of code and it seems to be working fine. I also tried to create another array that prints random numbers and get the same error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arraysize = 10;
    int myList[arraysize];
    
    int copyArray[arraysize];
    for(int index = 0; index < copyArray; index++){ 
    // Comparison between    pointer and integer ('int' and 'int *')
   
        
    }
    //display the copied array;
    
    //initializing arrays with random numbers
    int randomlist[arraysize];
    //seed a random number generator
    srand(time(0));
    //generate randim numbers between 1 and 100;
    for(int index = 0; index < randomlist; index++){
    //Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'int *')
        
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the exact line of code that gives you the error.

Comment: Your code isn't valid C++ code, as C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Modify the declaration of `arraysize` to become `constexpr size_t arraysize = 10;`

Comment: ive deleted the unnecessary code and only added the part that is giving me the error

Comment: And now you've delete too much. Please read about how to create a [mcve].

Comment: in `index < randomlist`, `index` is an `int`. `randomlist` is an `int[10]` or `int*`, but definitely not an `int`.

Comment: I am supposed to create a new array that will use the const int at the top of the program. the reason why I have int randomlist[arraysize]; the for loop created is to run through 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

The problems are the comparisons `index < copyArray` and `index < randomlist`.

Both `copyArray` and `randomlist` are *arrays*. The will decay to pointers to their first element. You compare the index with the pointer, which makes no sense.

I assume you want to compare to the array size, i.e. `index < arraysize`. Which you incidentally had for the first loop in the original code you showed (`for(int count = 0; count < arraysize; count++)`.

Comment: ok this makes more sense, thank you